# Is there an application for sharing wi-fi passwords?

Tags: ios, wifi

There are a lot of public wi-fi networks (diners, restaurants, cafes, universities). They are password protected. The password rarely (if ever) changes (only mcdonalds prints a temp password on the receipt).

I'm so very tired of asking for the password. I need to find a waiter. Sometimes they tell you a password that is not correct. Means I have to ask again.

**Is there an application that shares wi-fi passwords between different people?**

**For example**, someone goes to Joe's Cafe, gets the wi-fi password from the waitress, and in the background (ideally) an application puts the password on a server. Then another guy/gal enters the cafe and automatically has the password from the same server and connects, to the wi-fi without having to talk to the waitress.

Thanks,

Comment: How would the application get WiFi password if it's not yet connected to the internet?

Comment: "The password rarely (if ever) changes" Then just save it to your kaychain. Next time you select that network on your device, you won't need to re-enter it. I believe iOS does this by default to any network you "remember" (log into at least once). Not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: @Peter, there are two possible solutions for this: 1) preload all passwords from a server. 2) use 3g for a second to get the desired password.

Comment: @cksum, you are correct. But I want to share passwords between users. If you enter a cafe and get the password from the waitress, I want an application that shares the password to my phone without me having to ask the waitress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched in the iOS AppStore. I didn't find such an application. I also looked in Cydia, but no such application exists. Android's Market also said no.

**Here are my thoughts on why such an application does not exist**:

1. Sharing someone else's wifi password is an issue. He/she gave it to you so you can have internet. He/she hasn't agreed that you share it with the world. In the case of internet cafes, they have passwords so that only clients can use their wi-fi.
2. I spoke with an company that develops iOS applications. They said no public API exists that allows the application to get saved wi-fi passwords or to make the phone connect to a new wi-fi network.
3. Such an application most probably will not be accepted in the iOS AppStore (I have been told from the same company)
4. There are issues with implementation. How without an internet would one get the password that is needed for a concrete wi-fi network? Preload all passwords in the application? Use 3g to get that specific password?

**Even though I think such an application would make people's lives a bit easier, I think there are too many problems for it to be implemented.**

Comment: Nothing (besides time and know how) stops you from creating a web site for sharing Wi-Fi passwords. You can even start with a shared Google spreadsheet and extend this if/when access volume raises.

Comment: @patrix This is even harder than asking the waitress. The solution must be easy to use